# Rails Product model with a Recipe of other products, through join table

Tags: ruby, activerecord, ruby-on-rails-5, associations

I have a model called `Product`, that represents items. What I now need is for `Products` to have a "`Recipe`" that represents a list of other products with a quantity. Basically, a Product will have many of self with X amount of it. I was thinking that creating a new table that has a `recipe_id` and a `supply_id` with an `amount` column would do. But I'm having trouble with the association syntax.
My new model would be:

```ruby
create_table :recipe_supplies do |t|
    t.integer :supply_id
    t.integer :recipe_id
    t.decimal :amount, default: 0
end

class RecipeSupplies < ActiveRecord::Base
    belongs_to :recipe, class_name: 'Product'
    belongs_to :supply, class_name: 'Product'
end
```

And so my Product model would have:

```ruby
class Product < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :recipe_supplies, class_name: 'RecipeSupply', foreign_key: 'recipe_id'
  has_many :supplies, through: :recipe_supplies

end
```

What I need is to be able to do `@product.recipe_supplies`, to check supply(product) amount, but also  have an easy way of getting the supplies, like `@product.supplies` and get all products marked as supplies. What I can't figure out is how to do a `@product.recipe`, to get the recipes where `@product` is a supply. Or maybe there is a better way of doing this, any help is appreciated. I have the feeling I'm not on the best/most efficient path here.

```ruby
2.6.5 :006 > @product.recipe_supplies
  RecipeSupply Exists (0.4ms)  SELECT  1 AS one FROM "recipe_supplies" WHERE "recipe_supplies"."recipe_id" = $1 LIMIT $2  [["recipe_id", 109], ["LIMIT", 1]]
  RecipeSupply Load (0.2ms)  SELECT "recipe_supplies".* FROM "recipe_supplies" WHERE "recipe_supplies"."recipe_id" = $1  [["recipe_id", 109]]
[
    [0] #<RecipeSupply> {
               :id => 1,
        :supply_id => 1,
        :recipe_id => 109,
           :amount => 10.5
    },
    [1] #<RecipeSupply> {
               :id => 2,
        :supply_id => 2,
        :recipe_id => 109,
           :amount => 22.3
    }
]
2.6.5 :007 > @product.supplies
  Product Exists (0.6ms)  SELECT  1 AS one FROM "products" INNER JOIN "recipe_supplies" ON "products"."id" = "recipe_supplies"."supply_id" WHERE "recipe_supplies"."recipe_id" = $1 LIMIT $2  [["recipe_id", 109], ["LIMIT", 1]]
  Product Load (0.3ms)  SELECT "products".* FROM "products" INNER JOIN "recipe_supplies" ON "products"."id" = "recipe_supplies"."supply_id" WHERE "recipe_supplies"."recipe_id" = $1  [["recipe_id", 109]]
[
    [0] #<Product> {
                                 :id => 1,
                               ...
    },
    [1] #<Product> {
                                 :id => 2,
                               ...
    }
]
```

Comment: add to Product: `has_many :recipes, class_name: 'RecipeSupply', foreign_key: 'supply_id'`. maybe it would be better to just add `Recipe` model.